# GWT setSkipRowHoverCheck on abstract cell table

Tags: gwt

I have set the flag skipRowHoverCheck to true on the AbstractCellTable through the setter. By setting a debug point on the method onBrowseEvent2 inside AbstractCellTable I can confirm that the flag is set to true.

The code never executes the block where the skipRowHoverCheck is checked for being true, so no   MouseOver browse events are added.

However, on debugging the project, the mouse over events are still caught and the row level hover events are picked up. This then makes the rows the mouse hovers over the selected row which is what we do not want.

Any advice on this would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `skipRowHoverCheck` flag is used to avoid `DOM` restyling of the hovered row and firing of `RowHoverEvent`s (handled by using `addRowHoverHandler(RowHoverEvent.Handler handler)`).

It is *not* used to avoid sinking the low-level `BrowserEvents.MOUSEOVER` and `BrowserEvents.MOUSEOUT` events. They are still fired, handled (with a no-op, if you have used `setSkipRowHoverCheck(true)`) and, if necessary, delegated to the underlying cell.

I don't know if I correctly understood your question, but this is the way the `skipRowHoverCheck` flag was meant to be.